# Strategy for using specific search keywords as filters

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm improving a search feature for my food-menu using Elasticsearch. Analytics show that our users are often typing food "Categories" into the search bar, like `sandwich`, `soup`, etc. In addition, people are typing things like `gluten free`.

What are some strategies for turning these "meta" level search terms into filters as opposed to query-terms?

I had the idea of creating a `meta-terms` index and having the documents in it have a String property that I could use to translate the term into an Elasticsearch filter. For example, gluten-free might have a property that's something like 
`"{"filter", "'filter': {'term': {'gluten-free': true}}"}`

That way I could first search the meta-terms index and parse out any filters found and use those, along with the rest of the user's search terms to search the menu-item index.

Is there a more "Elaticsearchy" way to do this?

Thanks!

(PS) Sorry… I guess I wasn't clear… Say the user searches `Seattle Sub`, which is a specific menu item. If I just do `menu_item/_search?q='Seattle Sub'`, the sandwich will be one of the top hits. But if I do `menu_item/_search?q='Sandwich'`, a *soup* might be a top hit, because it's description my say something like "Tastes great with the grilled cheese sandwich". So— @OshoNot's right that If I search for the term `sandwich` in the `tags` property, all the returned items will indeed be sandwiches— But (and here's the crux of my question ) How would my code "know" to search the `tags` property? If I search for `Seattle Sub` in the `tags`, I'll get 0 results.

In other words— for some user search queries I want to search the `tags` field, and for some I want to search the `name` field. How do I target the correct fields based on user's search queries?

Answer (score 0):

Kelly Bennett,

You can use an array datatype field to have tags, and insert any categories in it:

```
PUT my_food_menu/my_type/1
{
  ....
  "tags":["gluten-free","lactose-free"]
  ....
}
```

And then you can apply an term filter:

```
GET my_food_menu/my_type/_search
{
  "query":{
     "term":{
        "tags":"gluten-free"
     }
  }
```

Hoje it helped

Comment: That's not _quite_ what I was asking. See edited question.